# Dropdown menu coding - mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I've a code snippet I'm trying to edit.

My website has a link navigation dropdown menu in place, but the default setting it to activate it on a mouse click, not to function on mouse hover as I would prefer.

Below is a snippet of the JS code - Anyone recommend a change to allow mouse hover to operate the dropdown?

EDIT - I've added "hover" instead of "click" but it did not work...

Thanks!

```
$("#nav .navbar-nav > li .dropdown-toggle").click(function () {    
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("open-nav")    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .mouseover() instead of .click()?

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you were not able to get `hover()` working.  I got it working just fine.

Here's a basic menu that might look similar to yours:

```
<div class="menu">Menu
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="link">Link 1</div>
        <div class="link">Link 2</div>
        <div class="link">Link 3</div>
        <div class="link">Link 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set the `nav` class to not display on the page load and turn the cursor into a pointer like so:

```
.nav {
    display: none;
}

.menu {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Then your jQuery function should look like this:

```
$('.menu').hover(function() {
    $('.nav').slideDown(500);
}, function() {
    $('.nav').slideUp(500);
});
```

Note the two parameters used for `hover()`, one for the mouse entering, and one for the mouse leaving.

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Xse4L/4/

Comment: The code is from a packaged html theme, so a lot is already written. I cannot add your custom code now I feel.

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           

            
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">link<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>

Comment: Why not just apply the same logic I used to your code?